# Return client IP and any proxy IPs in nginx

Tags: nginx

A couple of years ago I configured an nginx installation to return the client's header (or at least past of it) in the response header when a request is made to a specific location on an nginx server. The idea being that from a client I could retrieve details on what the server was seeing as my IP and also if any proxies (X-Forwarded-For) were involved.

Unfortunately the VPS provider I was using managed to lose my VPS thanks to disk failure and I can't find my notes on this anywhere! Can someone please tell me I'm not going mad and it is possible to do this?! I seem to remember it was fairly simple to do. It may have involved Openresty, but I don't know for certain.

I realise it's possible to do something like this in PHP or another language, but the solution I had was so simple I'd really like to track it down.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever you like in your server/location/whatever block:

```
add_header X-Forwarded-List $http_x_forwarded_for;
add_header X-Remote-IP $remote_addr;
```

You can arbitrarily inspect the headers of the request with the `$http_whatever_lowercased_header` variable (dashes downed to underscores) and simply add it to the response header, to check for the X-Forwarded-For stuff, and `$remote_addr` gets the IP of the incoming request (see the list of variables at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables and how to use `add_header` at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header. Verified working on my webserver just now.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that - it's working now! I realised following those links that on the new server I only had the basic nginx install, so that didn't help either. I'm now able to pass back those details to the client. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: No problem. You can also do it in the response body with `return 200 $http_x_forwarded_for` or `return 200 $remote_addr` (though only one argument is permitted, so you would have to add some logic to concatenate the two into a single variable if you wanted to do both at once - I think it's more elegant to use the custom headers, though.